# Client for API Gateways

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, wso2

I am new to API gateways and am trying to understand how they work. I am using WSo2 but figured they all probably work on same fundamentals.

1. I have a backend API written in SOAP which works fine.
2. I created a WSo2 API that connects to my backend SOAP API through swagger and works fine.
3. I also ran Wso2 endpoint from SOAP ui and got my response.

Next step is to create a client that will invoke WSo2 API and will eventually hit the backend SOAP API and get a response back. Should I use SOAP Backend API WSDL to create java objects while writing client for WSO2 API I created in step 2?

So:

```
wso2 client -> wso2 API -> backend SOAP API
```

and I create backend SOAP API WSDL to create java objects for wso2 client?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with MuleSoft. Even if the concepts are similar, the implementations are different, and you are asking for a response specific to WSO2.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for REST APIs the gateways expose OAS documents and you can use those to generate REST API clients.

However, in case of SOAP APIS, the gateways mostly work in passthrough manner. In that case, if you want to generate a client you can use the backend WSDL.